# GetAsyncKeyState() returns wrong value for VK_LCONTROL parameter when right alt is held down

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts

I wonder if I did something incorrectly, or if this is a Windows bug. Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        bool rightAltMod = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RMENU);
        bool leftControlMod = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL);
        //press and hold right alt to see the bug
        cout << "rAlt pressed " << rightAltMod << ", lCtrl pressed " << leftControlMod << "\n";

        quit = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The bug(?) is when I press and hold <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd>, `GetAsyncKeyState()` also detects it as <kbd>Left-Ctrl</kbd>.

If this is a bug, is there any workaround for it?

I have no ideas except direct access to keyboard buffer using assembler.

I'm developing on Windows 10 x64 21H1.

Comment: You should test only the highest-order bit of the return value. The correct way to use the function is as follows: `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) & 0x8000`

Comment: Thanks, sadly that didn't helped :/

Comment: Alternatively: `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) < 0` since the return value is signed and the high bit is the sign bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what causes the behavior - it is related to keyboard layout. The bug occurrs on Polish-programmers layout, after switching to EN-US layout it works fine.
Well, still I'll need to solve the problem, but for that I'll create a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce it with the following modified code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        SHORT rightAltMod = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RMENU);
        SHORT leftControlMod = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL);
        //press and hold right alt to see the bug
        if (rightAltMod != 0)
        {
            std::bitset<16> y(rightAltMod);
            cout << "rAlt pressed " << y;
        }
        if (leftControlMod != 0)
        {
            std::bitset<16> z(leftControlMod);
            cout << "lCtrl pressed " << z;
        }
        if (rightAltMod || leftControlMod)
        {
            cout << "\n";
        }

        quit = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And When I press and hold *Right-Alt*, the following snapshot is produced.
[image]